# MySQL: Searching same table multiple times with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I am writing a script to do a partial-word search on messages for a user. Each conversation has a mail_id, and each individual message has a msg_id.

I have a table, mail_word_index, which contains a row for each word in a message.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail_word_index` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dest_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mail_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msg_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `word` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dest_id` (`dest_id`,`word`),
  KEY `sender_id` (`sender_id`,`word`),
  KEY `multiple_words` (`mail_id`,`msg_id`,`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;
```

I have a query which takes 0.01 seconds to finish

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.mail_id FROM mail_word_index AS w1,
mail_word_index AS w2 
WHERE w1.sender_id=1 
AND w1.word LIKE 'str%' 
AND w1.mail_id=w2.mail_id 
AND w1.msg_id=w2.msg_id 
AND w2.word LIKE 'con%' LIMIT 20
```

However, searching one word at a time only takes 0.002 seconds to finish each one, and 0.004 seconds total:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.mail_id FROM mail_word_index AS w1 
WHERE w1.sender_id=1 AND w1.word LIKE 'str%' LIMIT 20

SELECT DISTINCT w1.mail_id FROM mail_word_index AS w1 
WHERE w1.sender_id=1 AND w1.word LIKE 'con%' LIMIT 20
```

The inner join seems to slow down the first query. How would I change the first query to make it faster?

The EXPLAIN tells me this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  w1  range   sender_id,multiple_words    sender_id   21  NULL    1   Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  w2  ref multiple_words  multiple_words  8   game-node4.w1.mail_id,game-node4.w1.msg_id  8   Using where; Using index; Distinct
```

Comment: You're *seriously* worrying about **6ms**??

Comment: Afaik, your `multiple_words` is already the best possible index for that query. It'll be slower because MySQL has to join.

Comment: As the table grows larger, and more words are searched at a time, the time difference between the query with the multiple joins, and the total time of each individual query grows much larger

Comment: @ZPS: How much larger?  Can you quanitfy?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN tell you about the "slow" query?

Comment: The big difference seems to show up when the first word matches a lot of rows. For example, searching a very common word will only take 0.002 seconds to complete, while searching for that common word as the first word in the query with the joins slows it down to 0.02 seconds.

Comment: So the reason is clear: all rows that are fetched in the first table are joined to the second (same) table in the complex query while the simple query searches the second table only once. I don't know if there are possibilities to improve the performance of the Joining query...

Comment: is there a reason you're not using free text search?

Comment: Yeah, kind of a silly reason, but full-text search considers a colon as a delimiter. I need my search to be able to handle the string "1:1:1" or "4:2:7" because that kind of string will be commonly used in my messaging system. I am unable to change this colon delimiter behavior without modifying mysql config files, which I do not have access to.

Comment: How about getting a more powerful hardware to meet your extraordinary requirements? You may also consider cluster, cloud etc instead of a single physical server to disperse the load and ensure your expectations regarding response times are met! Quality response time requires a quality bank balance too!

Answer (score 0):

In this case create index multi for w1:

```
ALTER TABLE `mail_word_index`
ADD INDEX `multi` USING BTREE (`sender_id`, `mail_id`, `msg_id`, `word`) ;
```